# Most idiomatic way to read a numeric environment variable in rust

Tags: rust

Learning Rust, and my project will need to load man environment variables. A lot of them are numbers and `env::var` returns a string.

For each of these variables, I have the constraints:

1. If the environment variable exists, try and use its value
2. If the value fails to parse as a number, use a default rather than panic
3. If the variable is set to "", use the default
4. If the variable is not set, use the default.

I've played around with it, done some reading, and come up with three approaches. But none of them seem completely clean, so I'm guessing I'm missing something fundamental.

This example runs and works, and shows the 3 approaches

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::env;

fn main() {

    let v1 = match env::var("XXPORT") {
        Ok(val) => match val.parse::<u16>() {
            Ok(val) => val,
            Err(_e) => 5000,
        },
        Err(_e) => 5000,
    };
    println!("v1 = {:#?}", v1);

    let v2: u16 = env::var("XXPORT")
        .unwrap_or("5000".to_string())
        .parse::<u16>()
        .unwrap_or(5000);

    println!("v2 = {:#?}", v2);

    fn default_port() -> u16 {
        5000
    }

    #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
    struct Config {
        #[serde(default = "default_port")]
        pub xxport: u16,
    }

    impl Config {
        pub fn from_envy() -> Self {
            let from_env = envy::from_env::<Config>();
            match from_env {
                Ok(config) => config,
                Err(_e) => Config { xxport: 5000 },
            }
        }
    }

    let v3 = Config::from_envy();
    println!("v3 = {:#?}", v3);
    println!("v3.xxport = {:#?}", v3.xxport);
}
```

- Using `match` is clean, but will be a pain when done for many variables
- Using `unwrap_or` just seems wrong (although it works and makes sense to me)
- Using `serde` seems like the tidiest solution, though the `Err` case will be a problem if only one of 100 variables failed to parse. Also the need to write a suite of functions for default values seems long-winded.

Comment: Using `envy` is fine. You could also use a command-line argument parser, e.g. [`clap`](https://crates.io/crates/clap) or [`bpaf`](https://crates.io/crates/bpaf). You could even combine it with [`dotenvy`](https://crates.io/crates/dotenvy) if you like using `.env` files

Comment: This will be deployed in kubernetes, with the variables coming from a config map (or three). Hence the potentially large number of them. One config map, many microservices.

Comment: Also, to get around needing "so many default functions". You can also `impl Default for Config`, then instead of tagging all fields with `#[serde(default = ...)]`. Then you can tag the struct with [`#[serde(default)]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#default)

Comment: Do you have a reference to the signature for the struct-wide default function? How do I know which field(s) need the default? And what if one or more of the variables is mandatory (no default)?

Comment: Ah, I see - you have to define a struct with default values for all fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to say upfront.

**DO NOT SILENTLY IGNORE ERRORS WHILE ALSO IMPLICITLY USING DEFAULT VALUES.**

This always ends up with a lot of headaches, when trying to figure out why something wrong happened. At the very least log error and only then resort to a default value.

---

Now that that's out of the way.

Using your second case with [`env::var()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.var.html) is perfectly fine. The hard part is of course that you have hundreds of variables. Using [`envy`](https://crates.io/crates/envy) and [`serde`](https://crates.io/crates/serde) is also fine.

Since you're dealing with environment variables, I'd actually suggest instead that you use a command-line argument parser, e.g. [`clap`](https://crates.io/crates/clap) or [`bpaf`](https://crates.io/crates/bpaf). You can use these to purely deal with env vars only. You could even throw [`dotenvy`](https://crates.io/crates/dotenvy) on top, if you like using `.env` files.

---

Before anything else. Instead of tagging all fields with `#[serde(default = ...)]`. You can actually just `impl Default for Config` and tag the struct itself with [`#[serde(default)]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#default).

In short, instead of this:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Config {
    #[serde(default = "default_a")]
    pub a: u32,
    #[serde(default = "default_b")]
    pub b: u32,
    #[serde(default = "default_c")]
    pub c: u32,
}

fn default_a() -> u32 { 1 }
fn default_b() -> u32 { 2 }
fn default_c() -> u32 { 3 }
```

You can do this:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(default)]
struct Config {
    pub a: u32,
    pub b: u32,
    pub c: u32,
}

impl Default for Config {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: 3,
        }
    }
}
```

If any field is missing, then those fields will be assigned the value of that field in `default()`.

---

Now, the actual hard part is that regardless of whether you use [`serde`](https://crates.io/crates/serde), [`clap`](https://crates.io/crates/clap), [`bpaf`](https://crates.io/crates/bpaf), or anything else. They usually don't support an easy way to do *"if err then use this value"*. Honestly, that's for good reason. Because it opens the door to huge headaches from a tiny typo.

However, if you truly want to do this, then it will require some boilerplate code to do so.

One solution, is that you can defer deserialization of `Config` to a separate `TryConfig`. The difference being that `TryConfig` mirrors all fields of `Config`. But instead of `field: T`, then in `TryConfig` it would be `field: Option<Result<T, E>>`.

---

However, `serde` does not implement `Deserialize` for `Result`. So we have to be creative. We can introduce an `enum TryParse<T>`. Which has 3 variants mirroring the 3 variants representable by `Option<Result<T, E>>`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum TryParse<T> {
    Parsed(T),   // Some(Ok(T))
    ParseFailed, // Some(Err(E))
    NotPresent,  // None
}

impl<T> TryParse<T> {
    fn unwrap_or(self, default: T) -> T {
        match self {
            Self::Parsed(val) => val,
            _ => default,
        }
    }
}

impl<'de, T: Deserialize<'de>> Deserialize<'de> for TryParse<T> {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        Ok(match Option::<T>::deserialize(deserializer) {
            Ok(Some(value)) => TryParse::Parsed(value),
            Ok(None) => TryParse::NotPresent,
            Err(_) => TryParse::ParseFailed,
        })
    }
}
```

Next we need to implement `TryConfig`. Remember, this one mirrors all fields of `Config`. The difference being that `T` is now `TryParse<T>`.

Then next, we `impl From<TryConfig> for Config`, so we can nicely convert from `TryConfig` to `Config`.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct TryConfig {
    a: TryParse<u32>,
    b: TryParse<u32>,
    c: TryParse<u32>,
}

impl From<TryConfig> for Config {
    fn from(cfg: TryConfig) -> Self {
        let default = Config::default();
        Self {
            a: cfg.a.unwrap_or(default.a),
            b: cfg.b.unwrap_or(default.b),
            c: cfg.c.unwrap_or(default.c),
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, we need to add [`#[serde(from = ...)]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#from) to `Config`. So `serde` deserializes `Config` through `TryConfig`.

```rust
use serde::{de::Deserializer, Deserialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(from = "TryConfig")]
struct Config {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
    c: u32,
}

impl Default for Config {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: 3,
        }
    }
}
```

*I'm not claiming this is the best or easiest solution. But it is the first and most straightforward solution (in my opinion) that came to mind.*

---

Now, again, the previous code is **silently ignoring any errors**. Which **I really do not recommend**. At the very least also implicitly log when `TryParse::ParseFailed` occurs.

Here's a version where `TryParse::ParseFailed` contains a stringified version of the deserialize error. As well as `.unwrap_or()` printing to stderr:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum TryParse<T> {
    Parsed(T),
    ParseFailed(String),
    NotPresent,
}

impl<T> TryParse<T> {
    fn unwrap_or(self, default: T) -> T {
        match self {
            Self::Parsed(val) => val,
            Self::ParseFailed(err) => {
                eprintln!("{err}");
                default
            }
            Self::NotPresent => default,
        }
    }
}

impl<'de, T: Deserialize<'de>> Deserialize<'de> for TryParse<T> {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        Ok(match Option::<T>::deserialize(deserializer) {
            Ok(Some(value)) => TryParse::Parsed(value),
            Ok(None) => TryParse::NotPresent,
            Err(err) => TryParse::ParseFailed(err.to_string()),
        })
    }
}
```

---

Note, there was an [issue on the serde repo](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1583) some years ago, with a discussion of this topic.

Comment: I eventually went with `serde` as, of all the variables, very few had a sensible default so I didn't need to write lots of functions for them.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `Result::ok()` and `Option::and_then()` to not pass the default value twice:

```rust
use std::env;

const DEFAULT_PORT: u16 = 5000;

fn main() {
    let port = env::var("XXPORT")
        .ok()
        .and_then(|port| port.parse::<u16>().ok())
        .unwrap_or(DEFAULT_PORT);
    println!("port is: {port}");
}
```

Or with logging:

```rust
use log::error;
use std::env;

const DEFAULT_PORT: u16 = 5000;

fn log_error<'a, E>(msg: &'a str) -> impl FnOnce(E) -> E + 'a
where
    E: std::error::Error,
{
    move |error| {
        error!("{msg}: {error}");
        error
    }
}

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();
    let port = env::var("XXPORT")
        .map_err(log_error("Port not found"))
        .ok()
        .and_then(|port| {
            port.parse::<u16>()
                .map_err(log_error("Invalid port number"))
                .ok()
        })
        .unwrap_or(DEFAULT_PORT);
    println!("port is: {port}");
}
```

Or with a generic function:

```rust
use log::error;
use std::env;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::str::FromStr;

const DEFAULT_PORT: u16 = 5000;

fn parse_env<T>(variable: &str) -> Option<T>
where
    T: FromStr,
    <T as FromStr>::Err: Display,
{
    env::var(variable)
        .map_err(|error| error!("{error}: {variable}"))
        .ok()
        .and_then(|raw| {
            raw.parse::<T>()
                .map_err(|error| error!("{error}: {raw}"))
                .ok()
        })
}

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();
    let port = parse_env("XXPORT").unwrap_or(DEFAULT_PORT);
    println!("port is: {port}");
}
```